# Do sign-language works typically have native sign-language titles?

Tags: title, american-sign-language-literature

While doing some looking into sign language literature for [a current topic challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/announcing-the-january-february-2023-topic-challenge-sign-language-literature), I noticed that all the works I was coming across, while entirely in sign language themselves, were given English/written titles. This makes sense, as I'm reading stuff on the Internet. Information will naturally be in a written-text format. However, it's also odd in the sense that it's as if all Japanese works had to be given an English title before people could discuss them.

Which leads me to suspect that my analogy perhaps doesn't actually apply, and the written title is purely for convenience, while a sign-language title could be used to discuss in sign language.

I should probably clarify what I mean by a sign-language title. Obviously the words of the written title could be directly translated into sign language. But sign language, especially its literature, can and does utilize a wide variety of techniques/movements/methods that can't be directly translated into a written language, at least not easily. Are these poetic methods used for native titles of sign-language works?

(This question may be over-broad or ill-posed, and if so, it's certainly because I have next to no knowledge of sign language or its literature. Also, while I've tagged with [american-sign-language-literature](/questions/tagged/american-sign-language-literature), answers from non-ASL sign language perspectives are welcomed)

Comment: I understand from British SL users I've met that it's normal for people to choose (or be given) a signed name that may or may not relate to the name they'd use in writing, or in English if they speak it. It might be the same for works - one title for print and another for sign.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica would you have the ability to ask your friends about their experience with sign language literature titles?